# Google Analytics 4 - Measurement Protocol hits not recording

Tags: api, google-analytics

I'm sending events hits to GA using the Measurement Protocol for GA4 but the hits are not getting recorded (they are showing on the GA dashboard even after waiting for more then 24 hours).

The URL I'm sending the POST request to:

https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=G-XXXXXXXXXX&api_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXX

The JSON body:

```
{
    "client_id": "XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX",
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "add_to_cart",
            "params": {
                "value": 50,
                "currency": "USD",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "item_id": "ITEM-SKU-001",
                        "item_name": "Product Name",
                        "item_variant": "Product Name",
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "price": "50",
                        "quantity": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The "client_id" is the value of the _ga cookie with "GA1.1." removed.

The above request returns an empty response body and a 204 http status code.

When I send the hit to the debug URL, I get the http status code 200 and the response body as:

```
{
    "validationMessages": []
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try sending it to the debug endpoint?   it can take up to 48 hours

Comment: I did tried sending it to the debug endpoint, I mentioned that in the question. I get http status code 200 and response body as: {"validationMessages": [] }

Comment: I have also waited more then 48 hours now. Non-MP event I send via gtag are appearing just fine.

Comment: @user20186893 Have you fixed a problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: You are missing : :`engagement_time_msec` within your params hash